# Geometric Convergent Series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I’ve been trying to understand and solve for this question but I don’t know where to start.

The sum of the first and second terms of a convergent series is $60$. The sum of all the terms is $108$. Determine the common ratio $r$ with $r > 0$, and the first term $a$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck. Do you know the formula for the sum of a convergent geometric series? Use mathjax to write mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Only the first 3 terms are integers: 36, 24, 16.

Answer (score 2):

Take $a$ to be the initial value of the series and $r$ to be the common ratio. We have two equalities from the information given:
$$a + ar = 60$$
$$\frac{a}{1 - r} = 108$$
The second statement comes from the formula for the value of an infinite geometric series. Manipulating the second equation yields:
$a = 108(1-r)$. Plugging that expression into the first equation gives:
$$108(1-r) + 108r(1-r) = 60$$
simplifying gives:
$$108r^2 - 48 = 0 $$
This polynomial has two roots at $r = \pm \frac{2}{3}$. But we know the value of $r$ must be between 0 and 1, so $r= \frac{2}{3}$

To get the value of $a$, plug in for $r$ in the first equation to get $\frac{5}{3}a = 60$, which gives $a = 36$.

Comment: This is a nice answer, so I upvoted it. In general, though, I'd rather people here waited to give a newbie OP a chance to improve the question by showing her work.

Comment: @EthanBolker Ahh sorrry, I'll wait longer next time. I'm new to this.

Comment: If you want to help a newbie OP who posts questions lacking context in the future, you may use the spoiler tag `>!` (or even mark your answer as community wiki).

Answer (score 1):

> The sum of the first and second terms of a convergent series is 60.

If the first term is called $a$ and the ratio $r$, then from this you have:
$$a+ar=60 \tag{1}$$

> The sum of all the terms is 108.

You probably know that the sum of a convergent geometric sequence is given by $\tfrac{a}{1-r}$; so you have:
$$\frac{a}{1-r} = 108 \tag{2}$$
Now combine equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ and solve for $a$ and $r$; can you take it from there?

---

Addition after comment; from $(2)$ you have $a=108(1-r)$ and plugging this into $(1)$ yields:
$$108(1-r)+108(1-r)r=60 \iff \ldots \iff 9r^2=4 \iff r = \ldots$$
Now  take the positive solution since it was given that $r>0$; then $a$ follows from $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please show me the substitution

Comment: @Jess Alright, I added a part.

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance

Answer (score 0):

In a geometric series with $r>0$  you know that the sum of the first two terms is $a(1+r)=60$ and the sum of all terms is $ a/(1-r)=108.$

Upon dividing we get $ 1-r^2 = 5/9$ which implies $r=2/3.$

Solve  $a(1+r)=60$ for $a$ and get $a=36.$